# Como obtener una variable de una respuesta ajax para poder imprimirla en un alert

Tags: javascript, ajax

estoy intentando obtener una variable de la respuesta de un ajax para poder imprimirla en un SweetAlert pero me marca undefinied, la variable que intento obtener es el nombre del usuario que se loguea para poder imprimirle un mensaje que diga "BIENVENIDO NombreUsuario", el nombre del usuario me llega bien en la respuesta ya que lo eh revisado en el log, pero aun no logro extraer esa variable dentro del ajax para poder sacar el mensaje..

este es el codigo php que envia la respuesta al ajax

```
if(password_verify($pass, $verify)){
    if ($rows->idProfile == 1 ){//si es admin

        session_start();
        $_SESSION["matricula"]=$_POST["password"];
        $_SESSION['nameUser'] = $rows->nameUser;
        $_SESSION['emailUser'] = $rows->emailUser;
        $_SESSION['accountUser'] = $rows->accountUser;
        $_SESSION['idUser'] = $rows->idUser;
        $_SESSION['tipoUser'] = "Administrador";
        $_SESSION['idProfile']=$rows->idProfile;
        $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => "exitoso",
            'name' => $rows->nameUser, //este es la variable que requiero extraer
            
           
        );
```

y este es la parte del ajax que recibe la respuesta y en la cual quiero extraer el dato e imprimirlo

```
success: function(response) //si la respuesta es exitosa
        {
            console.log(response);
            var resultado=JSON.parse(response);//parseamos el resultado a JSON
           if(resultado.respuesta == "exitoso"){//comparamos si lo que tiene el JSON es igual a exitoso
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR' +resultado.respuesta.name,//Aqui intento extraer la variale
                
               
              })
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     window.location.href = "catalogos.php";//redirigimos a index despues de 3 segundos
                 }, 2000); 
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segun tu respuesta php, estas generando una respuesta con los siguientes valores:

```php
$respuesta = array(
   'respuesta' => "exitoso",
   'name' => $rows->nameUser,
);
```

y en tu ajax tienes lo siguiente:

```javascript
var resultado=JSON.parse(response);
/*
donde tu variable resultado tendrá la forma

resultado: {
   "respuesta": "valor que retorne el back en tu respuesta",
   "name: "valor que retorna el back en tu respuesta"
}

*/
```

por lo tanto corrigiendo tu código en la variable y a la propiedad que buscas, tendrías lo siguiente:

```javascript
title: 'BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR' + resultado.name
```

Comment: Gracias DavElsanto, era justo lo que me hacia falta, tenia un error y era ese.. me sirvio tu ayuda

Comment: @WalterLopezCruz, si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada, es la mejor forma para que otros usuarios con problemas similares sepan que puede serles útil. Lo mismo aplica a todas las otras preguntas que has realizado.